# What is the difference between the F-test and the Wald / Likelihood Ratio / Score tests of linear models?

Tags: regression

In statistical inference, it's common that investigators will report the results from Wald tests for simple univariate inference or likelihood ratio tests for nested models. However, in regression modeling, under standard assumptions about the normality of errors, the F-test is exact and equally powerful in finite samples relative to the other tests. It's commonly included in statistical output, yet it's not favored for inference.

Can someone explain why the F-test is not used?

Comment: I know of *lots* of tests that might have these abbreviations. Could you please write out their names and, if possible, provide references? We also need some context to help narrow this question: what kinds of applications are you interested in?

Comment: @whuber: I think he meant Wald, Likelihood ratio and Larange Multiplier tests. Does F test not belong to any of likelihood ratio, Wald and score tests?

Comment: Or Wilcoxon, Logarithmic regression, and Linear Model. Once again, context matters: the F test is applied in various circumstances (ANOVA, multiple regression, comparing homogeneity of variances, etc.) and has slightly different justifications and assumptions in each.  So we're left guessing what is being asked: this question is currently too vague to have a clear objective answer.

Comment: I added a revision to the content so that it more closely asks what  I am 90% certain @Arumairajan is trying to ask.

Comment: I mentioned W (Wald), LR (Likelihood Ratio), LM (Lagrangian Multiplier) Tests.

Comment: You seem to say that for multiple linear regression with normal errors Wald, LR and LM are more popular than F test. That's just not true. For that standard setup, F is the most popular, and the situation reverses for other GLMs such as Negative Binomial regression.